# Mutable borrow conflict from unrolled loop

Tags: rust, lifetime

Consider the following code ([Playpen](http://is.gd/YeSIOf)), which is meant to simply parse input from stdin and put each line and a reference to that line in a structure:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::BufRead;

struct Line<'a> {
    text: Box<String>,
    column: &'a str,
}

fn main() {
    let column = 1;
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut lines: Vec<Line> = Vec::new();

    for line_res in stdin.lock().lines() {
        lines.push(Line {
            text: Box::new(line_res.unwrap()),
            column: "",
        });

        let line = lines.last_mut().unwrap();
        line.column = line.text.split_whitespace().nth(column)
                      .unwrap_or("");
    }
}
```

That is, `Line::column` should refer to `Line::text`.  Note that I set `column` to `""` initially (and modify it later) because I am not aware of a way to refer to the `text` element at creation time.

Unfortunately, the above code does not compile, spitting out the following very obtuse error message:

```
<anon>:15:3: 15:8 error: cannot borrow `lines` as mutable more than once at a time
<anon>:15       lines.push(Line {
                ^~~~~
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
<anon>:14:2: 23:3 note: expansion site
<anon>:20:14: 20:19 note: previous borrow of `lines` occurs here; the mutable borrow prevents subsequent moves, borrows, or modification of `lines` until the borrow ends
<anon>:20       let line = lines.last_mut().unwrap();
                           ^~~~~
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
<anon>:14:2: 23:3 note: expansion site
<anon>:24:2: 24:2 note: previous borrow ends here
<anon>:9 fn main() {
...
<anon>:24 }
          ^
<anon>:20:14: 20:19 error: cannot borrow `lines` as mutable more than once at a time
<anon>:20       let line = lines.last_mut().unwrap();
                           ^~~~~
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
<anon>:14:2: 23:3 note: expansion site
<anon>:20:14: 20:19 note: previous borrow of `lines` occurs here; the mutable borrow prevents subsequent moves, borrows, or modification of `lines` until the borrow ends
<anon>:20       let line = lines.last_mut().unwrap();
                           ^~~~~
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
<anon>:14:2: 23:3 note: expansion site
<anon>:24:2: 24:2 note: previous borrow ends here
<anon>:9 fn main() {
...
<anon>:24 }
          ^
<anon>:20:14: 20:19 error: cannot borrow `lines` as mutable more than once at a time
<anon>:20       let line = lines.last_mut().unwrap();
                           ^~~~~
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
<anon>:14:2: 23:3 note: expansion site
<anon>:20:14: 20:19 note: previous borrow of `lines` occurs here; the mutable borrow prevents subsequent moves, borrows, or modification of `lines` until the borrow ends
<anon>:20       let line = lines.last_mut().unwrap();
                           ^~~~~
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
<anon>:14:2: 23:3 note: expansion site
<anon>:24:2: 24:2 note: previous borrow ends here
<anon>:9 fn main() {
...
<anon>:24 }
          ^
error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
```

Surely this is nonsense!  The line conflicts *with itself*, among other things.  The only clue that I can see in this error is the fact that the loop is being unrolled.  However, shouldn't all the borrows made in the loop expire at the end of each iteration?

What is the actual semantic issue with the above code, and what is the fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible in Rust to have a reference to something in the same structure.

Think about it:

```
struct Line<'a> {
    text: Box<String>,
    column: &'a str,
}
```

What is `'a` intended to be? The lifetime of the `text` field (by the way, the `Box` wrapping around a `String` is completely superfluous). You thus can’t express the type until it already exists.

If such a reference *were* permitted, you’d run into problems like this:

```
let mut line = Line { text: "foo".to_owned(), column: "" };
line.column = &self.text;
line.text = "bar".to_owned();
// Uh oh, column is now invalid, pointing to freed memory
```

There is no way around this while the two values are stored together; they must be stored separately. The workaround that is most likely to be suitable for your case is to store indexes, e.g. start and end indexes as `(usize, usize)`.

Now: why these particular errors? It comes down to what `'a` is being inferred as; your vector of lines is `Vec<Lines<'x>>` for a single lifetime `'x`: *each `Lines` instance has the same lifetime*. This means that the inferred lifetime must be greater than that of the loop, and so each iteration of the loop does indeed keep a mutable reference alive, and so the line does in fact conflict with itself (or rather, a previous iteration) in that way. The loop is not unrolled—it’s just the borrows from the loop are indeed still alive.

Comment: That makes sense.  Is there a good way to get a `(usize, usize)` from the `&str` returned by `String::split_whitespace()`?

Comment: @thirtythreeforty: for a *good* way, there’s also the unstable [`subslice_offset`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.subslice_offset) method; for stable Rust, you can use pointers to the same effect: http://is.gd/ES2UYZ.

Comment: I think you're right. The former is what I want, but the second will work fine. I'm impressed that as_ptr() isn't marked unsafe.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty: The only operation on raw pointers that Rust considers unsafe is *dereferencing* the pointer. Other operations, such as comparisons, are not memory unsafe (but that doesn't mean they are necessarily correct), as they're just about manipulating integers in disguise.